# PowerShell get-ADUser missing some information

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm writing a function that will grab information from an AD group and will export it into a csv file. I'm trying to grab the name and description of the users but the description is missing for a couple of the users in the output CSV. Here's my code:

```
function Get-UserInfo{
param(
    [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup]$DomainName
    )
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $DomainName |  #get the group of users specified
ForEach-Object {  #For each object grabbed
$test = Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties * | Select-Object Description,Name #grab the Name + Description from each user
[pscustomobject] @{       #once data is grabbed send to custom object
Name = $test.Name
Description = $test.Description
}
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Test.csv    #Export information into CSV
}
```

Whats confusing is if I run

```
Get-ADUser -Identity "User" -Properties *
```

in the console for one of the users without a description their description shows up. I think it could be an issue with the way I'm pipelining but I'm not sure. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that with parameter `$DomainName` you actually mean `$GroupName`.

When you only need two properties returned, do not use `-Properties *` because when asking for **ALL** properties, you are wasting time and memory.

`Get-ADGroupMember` can return objects of type computer, group or user, and because you only want users, you should filter the result.

Try

```
# get all user objects that are member of the group and collect the data in variable $result
$result = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName |    # get the group of users specified
    Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } |      # filter users only (skip groups and computer objects
    ForEach-Object {
        # Get-ADUser by default returns these properties"
        # DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
        Get-ADUser -Identity $_.DistinguishedName -Properties Description | 
        # select and output the wanted properties as object. 
        # this will be collected in variable $result
        Select-Object Name, Description           
    } 

# now you can display on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# and export to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Test.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This fixed the issue, thanks for the advice with filtering the results. That was the next task after getting the CSV file :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, first of all, *AD Groups* can have members other than *user objects*, you need to filter them. I would also recommend you to not hard code paths (`Export-Csv`) inside of functions.

```
function Get-UserInfo{
param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
    [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup]
    $DomainName
)
    
    @(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $DomainName).Where({
        $_.ObjectClass -eq 'user' # => Groups can have other object types
    }) | Get-ADUser -Properties Description | # => Takes DN from pipeline
    Select-Object Description, Name |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Test.csv
}
```

Instead of having `Export-Csv` inside the function you could remove it then you could do something like this with your function:

```
Get-ADGroup 'somegroup' | Get-UserInfo | Export-Csv path/to/csv.csv
```